# Apache POI release 3.16 no longer working on Android?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

after switching from Apache POI release 3.15 to 3.16 (https://poi.apache.org/), my app crashes with this exception:

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;
                                                                               at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$HSSFColorPredefined.<init>(HSSFColor.java:113)
                                                                               at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$HSSFColorPredefined.<clinit>(HSSFColor.java:55)
                                                                               at org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$BLUE.<clinit>(HSSFColor.java:549)
```

I realize that this is because java.awt.* is not available on Android, but wonder why I didn't encounter this issue using the 3.15 release? My code has not changed. Is there a solution to be able to use the 3.16 version on Android?

Comment: Seems to have been introduced via SVN r1779866, Bug 59836... Can you stick to XSSF/.xlsx files? These should still work fine.

Comment: The above did fix the problem: I switched from HSSF to XSSF.

Comment: See also https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61004 for the related bug-entry where possible solutions are discussed.